# What difference does it make what values you put on either side of a equals sign?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, integer

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = input.nextInt();
        int[] grades = new int[size];

        for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
            int x = input.nextInt();
            grades[i] = x; **<<<<<< When i use this one i get the correct answer and i can input some numbers and they show up in a array**
            x = grades[i]; **<<<<<< However here i input my numbers but the array shows up as zeros only. Why?**

    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(grades));

        }
```

Comment: `=` is not mathematical equals, it's *assignment*. `A = B` means "Give `A` the value of `B`". That's not a symmetrical operation.

Comment: Assignment is always **FROM** the right **TO** the left.  If your question is different then I don't understand, please add some commentary to the question itself.

Comment: Try `myvar = 3` and `3 = myvar` and see what happens ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is not mathematical equals, it's *assignment*.

In Java, `A = B` means "Give `A` the value of `B`".

That's not a symmetrical operation, because you've changed the value of `A` afterwards, but not `B`.

As such, `grades[i] = x;` is assigning the value you've just read from the scanner to an element of the array; but `x = grades[i]` is overwriting the value you just read with whatever was stored in that element of the array.

By default, Java arrays are filled with zeros; if you don't assign different values to the elements, that's what you'll print.

Comment: "mathematical equals" in many programming languages is `A == B` and compares two values without altering them.  `A = B` will alter the contents of `A`, and also returns the same value as `A` to be used in later calculation, if needed.